# Setting up Google Analytics for FAQ-style JavaScript clicks

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have set up on my page a FAQ section based on this kind of code:

```
<script>
  function toggleElement(id) {
    if(document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none') {
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
    } else {
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>

<p><a href="javascript:toggleElement('a1')">1. QUESTION</a></p>

<div id="a1" style="display: none;">
<p style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102);"> <big>ANSWER</big></p>
```

Is there a way to configure Google Analytics to track (through Events?) the individual clicks on each question? I don't have many questions there (about 10), but I would still like to know about which ones are most relevant to my visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Analytics events for this.

In your HTML you can do something like this:

```
<p>
<a href="javascript:toggleElement('a1')"
   onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'FAQ', 'Open question', '1']);">
1. QUESTION
</a>
</p>
```

See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide for more information about it.

Comment: Sometimes I feel lost with Google's Documentation :D
Thank you all